# Can I render this collection without using .each()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

I'm new to ruby, but it seems like if I have a collection of things, I should be able to render them either in a loop or [by defining a `:collection`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails).

Here, each garden may have many plants assigned to it.  I have a partial that renders plants in a "card" layout.  This view correctly renders the plants for each garden:

**views/gardens/show.html.haml**

```
.row.plant-cards
  - @garden.plants.each do |plant|
    = render("shared/plants/card", {plant: plant, garden: @garden} )
```

**views/shared/plants/_card.html.haml**

```
.col-md-2
  .plant.thumbnail.text-center
    = button_to("+", add_to_garden_path(plant, @garden.id), {method: :post ,remote: true})
    = link_to(plant) do
      = image_tag("http://lorempixel.com/g/150/150/food/",:alt => plant.name)
      %h4.plant__title.caption= plant.name
```

I am trying to update the rendered plants on the garden page via ajax.  It seems that I need to stick the output of the rendered plant "cards" in the `.html()` function and using the `.each()` seems clumsy for that.  It seems like I should be able to set the plants as the `:collection` like I'm trying to do below, but that doesn't work:

**views/plants/add_to_garden.js.erb**
(sorry for mixing haml/erb - I'm exploring that too)

```
<% flash.each do |key, message| %>
  $("#flash").html("<%= j render partial: "shared/flash_message", locals: {key: key, message: message } %>");
<% end %>
$(".plant-cards").html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/plants/card', :collection => @garden.plants, :locals => {garden: @garden} %>");
```

When I make the ajax call to my application I get this runtime error:

```
Started POST "/plants/2/add_to_garden/1" for ::1 at 2016-12-30 20:32:18 -0500
Processing by PlantsController#add_to_garden as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"qJU/CEZudZFP9l6r1qdAlXJQrfY7fB0aZHmjRJh2yQO0IzxilP47mP2UjDDAmBNJouFtoAWkv/hJ2gCNR5BpgQ==", "id"=>"2", "garden_id"=>"1"}
  Garden Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `gardens`.* FROM `gardens` WHERE `gardens`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Plant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `plants`.* FROM `plants` WHERE `plants`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `gardens_plants` (`garden_id`, `plant_id`) VALUES (1, 2)
   (160.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered shared/_flash_message.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Plant Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `plants`.* FROM `plants` INNER JOIN `gardens_plants` ON `plants`.`id` = `gardens_plants`.`plant_id` WHERE `gardens_plants`.`garden_id` = 1
  Rendered shared/plants/_card.html.haml (29.7ms)
  Rendered plants/add_to_garden.js.erb (42.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 238ms (ActiveRecord: 162.9ms)

NameError - undefined local variable or method `plant' for #<#<Class:0x007fdf9be0f6c8>:0x007fdf9bce6350>:
  app/views/shared/plants/_card.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_shared_plants__card_html_haml___4163891484537289381_70299132319600'
  ...
```

Comment: In rails there are often multiple ways to do things. Your approach of interpolating html into javascript is not really necessary. You can just as easily put the html in a hidden node and reference it from javascript using id

Comment: Try using like this: `<%= j render partial: 'shared/plants/card', collection: @garden.plants, as: :plant, locals: { garden: @garden } %>`

Comment: @Deep - Yes!  Perfect.  I forgot that you can specify a collection `as:` something but that was the problem I was circling around - thanks.

Comment: @maxple, My purpose here is to refresh the plants when an new one is added to the garden.  If I understand you correctly I don't think I could place the html in a hidden node, right?  Because that html will become outdated as new plants are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put @Deep's answer into a question, he suggested

> Try using like this: `<%= j render partial: 'shared/plants/card', collection: @garden.plants, as: :plant, locals: { garden: @garden } %>`

Specifying the collection @garden.plants as `:plant` did the trick.